# node-oracledb get the output parameter

Tags: node.js, node-oracledb

I have the code below for our ERP system with IFS. the code calls a stored procedure after setting all the parameters. p3 is an inout parameter and it returns a value after execution. my question is how to read p3 after procedure execution.

```
 DECLARE
        p0   VARCHAR2(32000);
        p1   VARCHAR2(32000);
        p2   VARCHAR2(32000);
        p3   VARCHAR2(32000);
    BEGIN
        ifsapp.client_sys.clear_attr(p3);
        ifsapp.client_sys.add_to_attr('IZIN_TALEP_NO', '0', p3);
        ifsapp.client_sys.add_to_attr('IZIN_KODU', '01', p3);
        ifsapp.client_sys.add_to_attr('COMPANY_ID', 'XXX', p3);
        ifsapp.client_sys.add_to_attr('EMP_NO', '123', p3);
        ifsapp.client_sys.add_to_attr('CIKIS_TARIHI', '2019-09-13-00.00.00', p3);
        ifsapp.client_sys.add_to_attr('DONUS_TARIHI', '2019-09-21-00.00.00', p3);
        ifsapp.client_sys.add_to_attr('ISE_BASLAMA_TARIHI', '2019-09-22-00.00.00', p3);
        ifsapp.client_sys.add_to_attr('SURE_GUN', '9', p3);
        ifsapp.client_sys.add_to_attr('SURE_SAAT', '0', p3);
        ifsapp.client_sys.add_to_attr('NOTLAR', 'jhfsdkjjhlfdskh g', p3);
        ifsapp.client_sys.add_to_attr('ADRES', '897549875498754', p3);
        ifsapp.TRIFM_IZINLER_API.NEW__(p0, p1, p2, p3, 'CHECK') ;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p3);
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN ifsapp.error_sys.err_security_checkpoint THEN
            RAISE;
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            ROLLBACK;
            RAISE;
    END;
```

I have try it this way too

```
..... ifsapp.TRIFM_IZINLER_API.NEW__(p0, p1, p2, p3, 'CHECK'); :mm :=p3;
```

and the node code is

```
...dbHelper.executeReturn(checkSql, [{
        mm : {
            dir: oracledb.OUT,
            type: oracledb.STRING
        }
    }], req, res, true).then(res => {
        return res;
    });
```

I receive this error

> NJS-044: named JSON object is not expected in this context

any help is appreciated

Comment: Search for the example with 'Jones' in the [node-oracledb doc](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#outbind)  You don't show the actual node-oracledb call but you almost certainly don't want the bind block to be `[{ ...}]`.  Since you are using a named bind use '{ ... }'.  Also you will need to set `maxSize` otherwise the default returned size will be 200 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by creating a function that warps the methods and returned p3 from function

```
ifsapp.TRIFM_IZINLER_API.NEW__(p0, p1, p2, p3, 'CHECK');
RETURN p3;
```